# codeigniter routes ошибка вывода страницы

Tags: codeigniter

Имеется контроллер:

```
public function page() { 
    $this->load->model('page_model');
    $id = $this->input->get('id'); 
    $page = $this->page_model->getPage($id); 
    $data['title'] = $page[0]->title;
    $this->load->view('page',$data);
}
```

Имеется модель:

```
class Page_model extends CI_Model {
    public function getPage($id=0) {
        $query = $this->db->get_where("pages",array("id" => $id));
        $data = $query->result();
        return $data;
    }
}
```

При переходе http://localhost/index.php/page/id=1 Выдает ошибку The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
По какой ссылке могу просмотреть страницу?

Comment: http://localhost/index.php/main/page?id=1 Решил)